# How to set different anchors in QML + JS for horizontal & vertical orientation

Tags: javascript, qml, positioning

I have qml model for layout and would like to have abality to rotate screen 90degrees. Everything with rotating works fine but i have an issue with positioning.

I have two squares. If view is horizontal - i would like to have them one next to the other horizontally, each of 1/4 screen width. And when creen is vertical: i would like to have them one over and one below, each of 1/2 screen width, look:

```
+-------------+    +---------+
|             |    |         | 
|   AAA BBB   |    |  AAAAA  |
|   AAA BBB   |    |  AAAAA  |
|             |    |  BBBBB  |
+-------------+    |  BBBBB  |
                   |         |
                   +---------+
```

I can set each anchor like: `anchors.left: horizontal() ? parent.left : id_of_a.left` 
where `horizontal()` is a js function, but it starts to look very unclearly..

How to set different anchors in different way depend on orientation?

Comment: I would suggest to keep away from your `horizontal()` function as it will not bind and thus not update, you should make it a property on the top-level item. If you don't like the inline if-statement you can also use States with [AnchorChanges](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-anchorchanges.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your condition to use this "isHorizontal" property, also you can add your own code to the latest if. Add this code to your main page.

```
property bool changeOfWidth: false;
property bool changeOfHeight: false;
property bool newOrientation: false;
property bool isHorizontal: false;

onWidthChanged: {
    changeOfWidth = true; 
    newOrientation = (changeOfWidth && changeOfHeight);
}
onHeightChanged: {
    changeOfHeight = true; 
    newOrientation = (changeOfWidth && changeOfHeight);
}

onNewOrientationChanged: {
    if (newOrientation) {
        changeOfWidth = false;
        changeOfHeight = false;
        isHorizontal = width > height;
        if (isHorizontal) {
            // landscape
            console.log("landscape");
        } else {
            // portrait
            console.log("portrait");
        }
    }
}
```

For Qt 5.2 and greater:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2;

property bool isHorizontal: 
    Screen.primaryOrientation === Qt.LandscapeOrientation ||
    Screen.primaryOrientation === Qt.InvertedLandscapeOrientation;

onIsHorizontalChanged: {
    if (isHorizontal) {
        // landscape
        console.log("landscape");
    } else {
        // portrait
        console.log("portrait");
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution seems very complicated, the same behavior is possible with a single line `readonly property bool isHorizontal: width > height`